# An "internal server error" aka 500 has perplexed me entirely - .htaccess slash php madness

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know what this error is, but I'm sure it has something to do with my recent change of .htaccess or something missing from it. I added a few lines of rewrite code to change "something.php" to "something" - it worked fine. When testing my website online for the last few stages of development, I wanted to see what type of errors I'll get by attempting to access folders, and files - 404, 403, 401 etc.

Lets get to the point! When I entered **....com/press** or **....com/press.php** it will take me to the page as expected. When I enter **...com/press/** I get a 500 error - yes it has a slash, but shouldn't I be getting a 404 error? I say this because the file **press.php** exists, but not the folder ***...com/press/*** - it doesn't even show my own custom error page!

After taking a look at what I put in this .htaccess file, I also want some additional help with .htaccess. Index should be index alone, the server shouldn't accept .php even if it is, if you know what I mean!

Thanks in advance

Code in .htaccess:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your rule as:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Index should be index alone, the server shouldn't accept .php even if
>   it is

You can use this so that if they using the php extension, it will redirect.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```